# Generate random Password with Special Characters?

Tags: apex, code, passwords

Is there a way to use the below code, but also add special characters?
I need to generate a random 8 character password, that includes special characters.
Is this possible? Any assistance will be welcomed

```
    public static String generatePassword(Integer len) {

        Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
        String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
        
        System.debug(key);

        return key.substring(0,len);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the related question, as it has a number of high quality options available for you to generate random strings using cryptographically secure random characters. You can adjust these algorithms to choose the one you like best and support the characters you want.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to focus on the bigger problem you're trying to solve here (i.e. tell us why you're trying to generate passwords). As it stands, the best approach here is likely to not try to roll your own password/login code and use the standard password/login functionality that Salesforce provides (because you're very likely to create a very flawed and insecure solution if you don't know the ins and outs of application security).

Comment: ...Also, in addition to Derek's comment, it is against the Master Service Agreement to "roll your own security" instead of using the appropriate Salesforce licenses built for the job (e.g. Communities users), so if that's your intent, you may want to look at using the appropriate user licenses.